# how to create active directory users with accountExpires attribute from java

Tags: java, ldap

I want to create an AD user with accountExpires attribute. I am doing like this

```
public boolean addUser(
            String firstName,
            String lastName,
            String userName,
            String password,
            String organisationUnit) throws NamingException {
        if (findUser(userName, firstName, lastName, organisationUnit)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            // Create a container set of attributes
            BasicAttributes container = new BasicAttributes();

            // Create the objectclass to add
            Attribute objClasses = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
            objClasses.add("top");
            objClasses.add("person");
            objClasses.add("organizationalPerson");
            objClasses.add("user");

            // Assign the username, first name, and last name
            String cnValue = new StringBuffer(firstName).append(" ").append(lastName).toString();
            Attribute cn = new BasicAttribute("cn", cnValue);
            Attribute sAMAccountName = new BasicAttribute("sAMAccountName", userName);
            Attribute mac = new BasicAttribute("msNPCallingStationID", "ab-ab-ab-b7-6t");
            Attribute principalName = new BasicAttribute("userPrincipalName", userName + "@atamunet.com");
            Attribute givenName = new BasicAttribute("givenName", firstName);
            Attribute sn = new BasicAttribute("sn", lastName);
            Attribute uid = new BasicAttribute("uid", userName);
            Attribute fullName = new BasicAttribute("displayName", "fullName");
            Attribute gender = new BasicAttribute("initials", "gender");
            Attribute dob = new BasicAttribute("description", "dob");
            Attribute FatherName = new BasicAttribute("physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "FatherName");
            Attribute Email = new BasicAttribute("mail", "Email");
            Attribute mobile = new BasicAttribute("mobile", "mobile");
            Attribute department = new BasicAttribute("department", "department");
            Attribute HallName = new BasicAttribute("streetAddress", "HallName");
            Attribute FacultyName = new BasicAttribute("company", "FacultyName");
            Attribute CourseName = new BasicAttribute("title", "CourseName");

            Attribute accountExpires = new BasicAttribute("accountExpires", new Date());

            //some useful constants from lmaccess.h
            int UF_ACCOUNTENABLE = 0x0001;
            //int UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 0x0002;
            int UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD = 0x0020;
            int UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = 0x0040;
            int UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 0x0200;
            int UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 0x10000;
            //int UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 0x800000;

            Attribute enabled = new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl", Integer.toString(UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT + UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD + UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD + UF_ACCOUNTENABLE));
            // Add password
            Attribute userPassword = new BasicAttribute("userpassword", password);

            // Add these to the container
            container.put(objClasses);
            container.put(sAMAccountName);
            container.put(principalName);
            container.put(cn);
            container.put(sn);
            container.put(givenName);
            container.put(uid);
            container.put(userPassword);
            container.put(mac);
            container.put(gender);
            container.put(dob);
            container.put(FatherName);
            container.put(Email);
            container.put(mobile);
            container.put(department);
            container.put(HallName);
            container.put(FacultyName);
            container.put(CourseName);
            container.put(fullName);
            container.put(enabled);
            container.put(accountExpires);

            // Create the entry
            try {
                ctx.createSubcontext(getUserDN(cnValue, organisationUnit), container);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "add");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I add user with accountExpires attribute. Is there anybody can help me. Without this line

Attribute accountExpires = new BasicAttribute("accountExpires", new Date());

Everything goes fine but I want the expiry date as well.

Comment: It's not clear your issue here, could you explain it better please?

Comment: I want to add an active directory user. Above code is working for me but I want to provide user's Account Expiry date. So can you help me how to use accountExpires attribute in java. I am trying to create user with account expiry date.

Comment: The *Account-Expires* attribute is an *Interval* not a date, according to the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675098(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If I want user account to be expired on 2nd June 2017, what will be the Java code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help what gave me the idea and this code worked for me

```
/**
     * Difference between Filetime epoch and Unix epoch (in ms).
     */
    private static final long FILETIME_EPOCH_DIFF = 11644473600000L;

    /**
     * One millisecond expressed in units of 100s of nanoseconds.
     */
    private static final long FILETIME_ONE_MILLISECOND = 10 * 1000;

    public static long filetimeToMillis(final long filetime) {
        return (filetime / FILETIME_ONE_MILLISECOND) - FILETIME_EPOCH_DIFF;
    }

    public static long millisToFiletime(final long millis) {
        return (millis + FILETIME_EPOCH_DIFF) * FILETIME_ONE_MILLISECOND;
    } 

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            String dateInString = "01-07-2017 10:20:56";
            Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
            final long dd = date.getTime();
            Attribute accountExpires = new BasicAttribute("accountExpires", Long.toString(millisToFiletime(dd)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the attribute to the current date, but this is not correct.

First of all because the attribute is an interval of 100-nanoseconds, according to the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675098(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684426(v=vs.85).aspx).

What you have to do is set your desired expiration date, then convert to the value of 100-nanoseconds, that in Java are represented by long.

Here is a trivial code example that show you how to do it with Java 8:

**UPDATED:**

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    // First you need to get the start date
    // according to the documentation it is
    // the 1th January of 1601
    cal.set(1601, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);

    // print the current date
    System.out.println(String.format("Start date: %tc", cal));

    Date startDate = cal.getTime();

    // Reset the calendar to today
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, System.currentTimeMillis());

    // Set the desired expiration date
    // here is 1 year in the future
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);

    // print the current date
    System.out.println(String.format("Expire date: %tc", cal));

    // Get the date from Calendar
    Date expireDate = cal.getTime();

    // Create an interval from the startDate to the expireDate
    // and convert it to nanoseconds interval
    long expirationInterval = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toNanos(expireDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime());

    // set the attribute value
    Attribute accountExpires = new BasicAttribute("accountExpires", expirationInterval);
```

Comment: But this is resulting an error: `Expire date: Sat Oct 14 09:31:51 IST 2017
Malformed 'accountExpires' attribute value`

Comment: @MohammadAmir sorry, I forgot the diff with the start date. Please have a look at my update.